# Unknown character in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I have a mysterious problem about Microsoft Word. I'm trying to edit a document which is converted from an image using Abbyy Reader.

I tried to remove the document's format but it didn't work. When I search bold format I see a square after the sentence which I didn't know what it is.

I'm attaching a screenshot for this mysterious box which is marked blue:

[image]

Hoping to find what this character is and how to remove it along with the other characters.

Comment: Copypaste it into https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/character-identifier

Comment: Another option is to select that character, then press Ctrl-H for search and replace. Have that character in the Replace box, and replace it with nothing. Boom.

Comment: Both methods did not work :)

Comment: If you can post your .dox file (or .docm or whatever) to a place such as a dropbox that others here can reach, someone may be able to work out what you are seeing. OTOH, if you are using a desktop version of Word and are in a position to use VBA, that couldl lead to an explanation. FWIW I thought this might be a situation where the blue block actually was the background color for a character such as a paragraph return, but I wasn't able to replicate that possibility here.

Comment: Hi Jonsson... This is the document:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J2QHlHNeGDxA4TX7j8nzfIU7anMWAv3c/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115504102394678441199&rtpof=true&sd=true

To find these spaces, just click search, then format search, then bold. You will see several lines appearing in the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

These are paragraph marks which are set to **BOLD**. If you <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> paragraph marks will be visible to you.

Comment: It didn't work. I have attached the word document. Try to search for "bold" format and you will see that a couple of lines have this character while others don't.